# Disable save as key for images

Tags: jquery, windows, internet-explorer, keyboard, galleria

I'm using Galleria Fullscreen theme and don't allow save as image (disable right click) via jQuery. This code:

```
$('img').live('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

This code working Firefox, Safari and Chrome Mac. I tested on Windows and don't allow right click. But when push a Windows key, get Save As Images. This is key:

[image]

How can I disable this key?

Comment: I answered this in 2004. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffdav/archive/2004/05/06/127443.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Also, it's worth noting that given the very nature of the web **all** the content of your website will be downloaded and saved on the client's machine in their cache (assuming they have it enabled). There will always be a method of saving a file found online to a local machine.

If you don't want someone to download your images or use them without credit, either watermark them, or don't put them online.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*"Humor should be allowed if they are answering the question."* [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16497/173320)

**The real answer, is that you can't.**

Comment: Humour?!? On stack overflow? Are you mad!

Comment: "Borrow" all the keyboards in the world, steal the offending key, and return them all to their rightful owners.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. I took the risk of getting downvotes, I just couldn't help it. The nerds attack gave me only two downvotes (until now...)

Comment: I'd delete it now before the n00bs start pwning your rep.

Answer (score 1):

In my website I used the script like this

```
    ///Disable Right Click
    var message = "Sorry! We are not allowed right click for SECURITY REASON.";

    ///////////////////////////////////
    function clickIE4() {
        if (event.button == 2) {
            alert(message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function clickNS4(e) {
        if (document.layers || document.getElementById && !document.all) {
            if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {
                alert(message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (document.layers) {
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
        document.onmousedown = clickNS4;
    }
    else if (document.all && !document.getElementById) {
        document.onmousedown = clickIE4;
    }

    document.oncontextmenu = new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

I hop it can help your case :-)

Comment: I hope I don't have to use your sites... That's a joke anyway, stopping only the less knowledgeable users. You can drag'n'drop the image, save the whole page, use Firebug, and so on, so your security is seriously flawed anyway, and you just annoy users that want to use normal browser functions (like changing language or accessing other context menu items).

Comment: Yes I understand what do u mean bro. But sometimes we need those funny funny things to put in our intranet site or internal web apps or blah blah. Cos manager wants. No choices. :) by the way I understand what do u want to say and just excuse only :D

Comment: I understand the "cos manager wants" part... :-) Pointy haired managers, I suppose. In this case, you should at least do the best you can, and in this case your answer (which I didn't downvote, BTW) can be useful. Hey, at least, it is can probably survive a quick (pointy haired) manager testing... I mostly wanted to point out, for those not aware of it, that this "solution" is (very) brittle.